# Can't get behat running on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink

I'm using Symfony 2(latest version) framework and I want to use behat.

I've already inited the **Features** folder inside my bundle with **Context/FeatureConext.php** and **/xxx.feature**

My behat.yml is located in **app/config** folder of Symfony 2
and is looking like this :

```
default:
  paths:
    features : %behat.paths.base%/../src/xxx/myBundle/features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  context:
    class:  FeatureContext
  formatter:
    name: progress
  extensions:
 Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
  mink_driver: true
  kernel:
    env: test
    debug: true
 Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
  base_url: 'localhost/web/app_dev.php'
  default_session: symfony2
suites:
  test_suite: 
      type: symfony_bundle
      bundle: 'xxxMyBundleBundle'
```

How do I exactly specify the path to my feature folder ?

Thanks you.

Comment: behat.yml should be located in the project root folder, not in app/config.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pierre for your answer.

Indeed, behat.yml should be in the root folder but I have read that there is a way to put it in the app/config folder.

Anyway, putting it in the root folder does the trick.